# Yii 1.1 - A non well formed numeric value encountered

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I have an error "A non well formed numeric value encountered"
in this code on my localhost:

```
Yii::app()->cache->set($cache_key, $res, 60*60*24*3);
```

It obviously points to "60*60*24*3". I know I can typecast it to integer
and problem is solved, but the same code works fine on server.

On my localhost I have php7.2 installed, and on server is old php5.3.

What could be the reason of problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think i found an answer. Offical documentation says that:

> Deprecated features in PHP 7.2.x ¶ Unquoted strings ¶ Unquoted strings
>   that are non-existent global constants are taken to be strings of
>   themselves. This behaviour used to emit an E_NOTICE, but will now emit
>   an E_WARNING. In the next major version of PHP, an Error exception
>   will be thrown instead.

Comment: `60*60*24*3` is not "unquoted string", it is expression which returns integer.

Comment: yes you are right. Actually instead of 60*60*24*3 there was CATEGORY_DEEP_CACHE_LIFETIME which was defined in config/consts.ini like CATEGORY_DEEP_CACHE_LIFETIME = 60*60*24*3

Comment: You should probably add this info to question - right now it does not make much sense since code you've shared should not produce such error.